# Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run this code in jupyter notebook but I am getting the following error for fuzzyset package. I am using fuzzyset version 0.0.9. Does anybody know how to convert these dictionary values to list?

```
    agrovocSimple = []
    with open('agrovocLabels.json') as data_file:
    agrovoc = json.load(data_file)
    results = agrovoc["results"]["bindings"]
    for entry in results:
        uri = entry["uri"]["value"]
        label = entry["label"]["value"]
        #agrovocSimple.append({"uri": uri , "name": label})
        agrovocSimple.append(label)

    ####instatiation of the fuzzyset for the mappings
    # allocate the FuzzySet object
    a=FuzzySet()
    for e in agrovocSimple:
       a.add(e)

    ####TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-19-bc4871be0e65> in <module>()
    17 a=FuzzySet()
    18 for e in agrovocSimple:
    ---> 19     a.add(e)

   fuzzyset\cfuzzyset.pyx in cfuzzyset.cFuzzySet.add()

   fuzzyset\cfuzzyset.pyx in cfuzzyset.cFuzzySet._add()

   TypeError: Expected list, got dict_values
```

Comment: It seems `FuzzySet.add()` does not like dicts and wants a list instead.  `label` appears to be a dictionary, but its needs to be a list.  Try `label = [entry["label"]["value"]]`.  Also please correct your indentation.

Comment: I am getting an error: TypeError: must be str, not list

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that library.  `set.add()` typically only allows one hashable item.  I'm not sure what `FuzzySet` is doing, but it should be easy enough to track down with `print` statements and `type()`.  This might be a good time to get familiar with the `%debug` option.

Comment: I checked the type of agrovocSimple and its string but still the code a.add(e) throws me an error. You can check the entire code at:https://github.com/bioversity/dataverse-dashboard-curation